HighCharts Line Chart - When pressed down get the corresponding X value and draw a line above it which also moves for dragging
I would like to achieve that if the user press his/hers finger down on the chart's area (not only on the plotLines only but anywhere in the chart) then I can get the X value and also drawing a line on top of it. If the user moves his/hers finger then the line's position also updates/moves and the value also updates. Similarly you can see in stock apps when you checking out your portfolio.

The closest I got is getting the X and Y coordinates but sadly It is only for if I click on the plotLines
        chart = chart.apply {
            marginRight = 40
            marginLeft = 0
            marginTop = 8
            marginBottom = 8

            plotOptions = HIPlotOptions().apply {
                series = HISeries().apply {
                    cursor = "pointer"
                    point = HIPoint().apply {
                        events = HIEvents().apply {
                            click = HIFunction(
                                HIFunctionInterface { var1 ->
                                    Log.d("eqweqeqew", "${var1.getProperty("x")}  ${var1.getProperty("y")}")
                                    "something"
                                },
                                arrayOf("x", "y"),
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

How can I achieve this?

When it comes to adding the vertical line, use crosshair:
val xaxis = HIXAxis()
xaxis.crosshair = HICrosshair()
options.setXAxis(ArrayList(listOf(xaxis)))

Getting values when dragging can be done via mouseOver instead of click:
mouseOver = HIFunction()

